# How to access multiple values of a CLI argument

Tags: javascript, node.js, command-line-arguments

I have a node JS script which reads arguments from command line by executing `./test.js -n name1 -r us-east`. Here there are two arguments `-n` & `-r` passed with appropriate value each. Now I have to introduce another argument `-i` which will receive atleast one value and atmost multiple values against it. Meaning the script is executed as:

```
./test.js -n name1 -i 100 101 103 -r us-east
```

1. How do I find the number of argument values against each argument, for instance in the above example argument `-i` has `3` values.
2. How to store these values into an array.

   ```
   var data = new Object();

   function usage()
   {
     return "test.js [-n|--name] [-i|--ids <id1 id2...>] [-r|--region] ";
   }

   function process_args()
   {
     var args = process.argv.slice(2);
     var i;
     for (i = 0; i > args.length; i++)
     {
           switch(args[i])
           {
           case "-n":
           case "--name":
                   i++;
                   if (i >= args.length)
                           error_exit_usage("Missing name argument");
                   data.name =args[i];
                   break;
           case "-i":
           case "--ids":
                   i++;
                   if (i >= args.length)
                           error_exit_usage("Missing ids argument");
                   /* TODO */
                   break;
           case "-r":
           case "--region":
                   i++;
                   if (i >= args.length)
                           error_exit_usage("Missing region argument");
                   data.region = args[i];
                   break;
            }
      }
   }
   ```

New to Node JS.

Comment: Is there a specific reason you are using your own implementation and not something existing like https://www.npmjs.com/package/nomnom ?

Comment: Can you use 100-101-103 argument like this

Comment: @FelixKling Currently the script takes `8` number of arguments in my implementation with the `switch case` method mentioned above, hence do not want to change it.

Comment: @Mytri In fact the values are of 10 digit account numbers. So that's kind of not possible.

Comment: But If you Give argument like ./test.js -n name1 -i 100 101 103 -r us-east every 100 101 103 will be counted as different index So can you give them Like ./test.js -n name1 -i  "100 101 103" -r us-east  so it will be treated as one String and one index

Comment: You can also check out https://www.npmjs.com/package/argumints. Its a NodeJS package that allows argument manipulation and expansion (even reads and parses JSON strings from CLI). get it easily from npm. <code>npm install argumints</code>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you could just look at the next arguments as long as they are IDs:

```
case "-i":
case "--ids":
  data.ids = [];
  while (/^\d+$/.test(args[i])) {
    data.ids.push(Number(args[i]));
    i++;
  }
  if (data.ids.length === 0) {
    error_exit_usage("Missing ids argument");
  }
  break;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function processArguments(args) {

    var options = {}, optionName = null;

    args.forEach(function (val, index, array) {
        if (val.indexOf('-') === 0) {   
            optionName = val.replace('-', '');
            options[optionName] = [];
        } else {
            if (optionName != null) {
                options[optionName].push(val);
            }
        }   
    });
    return options;
}

var options = processArguments(process.argv);

console.log(options['n']);
console.log(options['i']);
console.log(options['r']);
```

Comment: if an option (ie. -n) is not given then typeof options['n'] === 'undefined'

Answer (score 1):

Use `commander` and coerce the i option to a list.  Pass it in as comma separated values.  See [examples](https://www.npmjs.com/package/commander#coercion).

Always search on npmjs.com or node-modules.com or use `modsearch` since there are many modules for common scenarios such as this.

Answer (score 1):

So one Approach which you can use is 
You can send argument like./test.js -n name1 -i "100 101 103" -r us-east

And later split them using [split function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) which will return array.

```
function process_args()
{
  var args = process.argv.slice(2);
  var i;
  for (i = 0; i > args.length; i++)
  {
        switch(args[i])
        {
        case "-n":
        case "--name":
                i++;
                if (i >= args.length)
                        error_exit_usage("Missing name argument");
                data.name =args[i];
                break;
        case "-i":
        case "--ids":
                i++;
                if (i >= args.length)
                        error_exit_usage("Missing ids argument");
                data.id=args[i].split(" ")
                break;
        case "-r":
        case "--region":
                i++;
                if (i >= args.length)
                        error_exit_usage("Missing region argument");
                data.region = args[i];
                break;
         }
   }
}
```